# Timer between Web layer and UI

Tags: jquery, spring, model-view-controller, jsp, timer

I need to check the performances between the layers.
How can I get the time spent by the request to fetch data from backend to UI?
I am using Spring MVC. I was thinking of putting some variables in response and read the respnse in jsp but I am not sure this is the good way to calculate. I making a jQuery ajax call to spring controller.

Answer (score 0):

> Well if you want to achieve this at a broad level then you should go
>   for a properly architectured tool for this.

I think [jProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/top10.html) will do for you in a number of scenarios that you have never even thought of. Have a check on it, it would be an add-on to your development lifecycle and time delays of calls memory management aspects etc.